# 委託 vs 託す vs 預ける

Tags: meaning, nuances

So I was studying my kanji when I read this sentence:

> 僕は、有り金をすべて彼に委託した。
>
> I trusted him with all the money I had.

If I changed it to these:

> 僕は、有り金をすべて彼に預けた。
>
> 僕は、有り金をすべて彼に託した。

How will the meaning or nuance change?

Comment: I did the perfunctory Google search and found this: https://hinative.com/ja/questions/4259467. The things I got from the link are that "委託 requires some sort of compensation for the service" and that "託す” is a bit more formal and is less frequently used than 預ける (which I think makes sense, considering that it's the first time I encountered it)

Comment: You can't use 委託 there. Do you perhaps mean the legal "trust"? Then it's 信託.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth Thanks for dropping by.  By "there," did you mean in this sentence「僕は、有り金をすべて彼に委託した。」? This is a sample sentence I found in an app.

Comment: @rebuuilt 僕はすべての資産を彼に委託した This one is okay but the sample your app is not the right one to write it down. Although many Japanese people say 僕は、有り金をすべて彼に委託した。 and don't notice it's not really good but many other people find it lame. In the first place 有り金 isn't a word for the educated man, it's not elegant.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka, thank you. I figured out too that sample sentences in the app aren't that reliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 僕は、有り金をすべて彼に委託した。

委託 is a financial/business term. This means "he" will manage the money on behalf of you, for a certain purpose, as a professional. If he is a businessperson, he may invest it to make more money and return the profit to you. If he is a lawyer, he may distribute the money to your bereaved family.

> 僕は、有り金をすべて彼に預けた。

This means "he" received the money, but he will keep it and eventually return it to the owner without touching it. The ownership is not transferred. Normally, people use banks for this purpose, but one may have to do something like this when a bank is not available for some reason.

> 僕は、有り金をすべて彼に託した。

This is like 委託する, but 託す is not a business term, so "he" does not have to be a professional. You may do this when you believe he can spend the money more wisely than you to achieve some goal, or when you know you cannot use it any more.

Answer (score 0):

預ける is when you hand over things to people only for safekeeping (and eventually returning).

託す is used more often in the sense of that you entrust tasks or things to people and also entrust them with the decision what to do with it.

Comment: Can 「預ける」 be also used with people? Jisho gives 「彼女は子供を叔母に預けた」 as example.

Comment: Yes you could say that.